Probability of a point in a continuous space
I'm trying to understand the concept of probabilities in continuous distributions, and I'm a bit confused.
Suppose we have a probability density function (PDF) for the duration of phone calls. It’s said that the probability of a call ending at an exact time x is zero. i.e. P(X=x)=0. However, every call does end at some point in time, so shouldn’t there be a chance a call could end at a specific time x? How do we interpret this zero probability if a call could theoretically end exactly at x?
Now, consider another scenario where the PDF shows a value of zero for certain times (for example, for very short calls). In this case, we would say that no call could end at those times, which intuitively makes more sense to me because those values are impossible.
Could someone help clarify why a probability of zero has these different interpretations in continuous distributions? Thanks!

The probability of something being $0$ does not mean that it "cannot happen". It's just that the probability of it happening is $0$. For example, take the uniform random variable $U$ in $[0,1]$. Recall the definition of a random variable. It is a function from a probability space (sample space) $\Omega$ to $\Bbb{R}$. So obviously for some fixed $\omega$, $U(\omega)$ will be a real number in $[0,1]$. But $P(U=x)=\int_{x}f(u),du=0$ as the integral of a function over a singleton set is $0$.

For another example, suppose you are tossing infinitely many coins. Then the probability that all the tosses are heads is $0$ as it's $(\frac{1}{2})^{\infty}$ (non-rigourously speaking). But there can be a scenario that all tosses will land heads. It's just that the probability of that happening is $0$.

In continuous distributions, the probability of a specific outcome is indeed zero.
To illustrate that the probability of a call ending at an exact time x is zero, consider an interval like  [0, 60]  minutes for call durations. There are an infinite number of possible values within this interval (e.g., 10.001 seconds, 10.002 seconds, etc.), so the chance of a call ending exactly at one specific moment out of an infinite number of possibilities is zero.
However, we normally use interval probabilities (e.g.,  $P(a \leq X \leq b)$ ) to describe the likelihood of events in continuous distributions. The probability density function (PDF) tells us how densely probability is packed around each point, but to get actual probabilities, we need to look over intervals.
